# SonarQube LDAP 2.0 configuration

Tags: active-directory, ldap, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I migrated from SonarQube 5.6.2 to 6.0. I was using the Active Directory Plugin for my LDAP integration with the following configuration:

```
sonar.security.realm=ACTIVE_DIRECTORY
sonar.authenticator.downcase=true
```

As Active Directory Plugin is not compatible with SonarQube 6.0, I was pushed to use LDAP 2.0 plugin.
I came up with the following configuration:

```
sonar.security.realm=LDAP
sonar.authenticator.downcase=true
ldap.url=ldap://ldap.mydomain.com
ldap.bindDn=myServiceAccount@mydomain.com
ldap.bindPassword=myPwd

ldap.user.baseDn=dc=my,dc=domain,dc=com
ldap.user.request=(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={login}))

ldap.group.baseDn=ou=Groups,dc=my,dc=domain,dc=com
ldap.group.request=(&(objectClass=group)(member={dn}))
ldap.group.idAttribute=sAMAccountName
```

and substantially it works.

Now my question is:
Is there a way to setup LDAP 2.0 plugin to simulate the user-id@domain schema. If not, how do I migrate my current user accounts towards the new one that are created based on the new schema (sAMAccountName only)?